# Correct way to convert Zip task `archiveFile` to an absolute path?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to remove usages of deprecated stuff from my Gradle scripts.
I noticed `archivePath` is supposed to be replaced by `archiveFile`.

What's the "right" way to convert `archiveFile` to an absolute path?

Here's my Gradle task:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip){
  ...
  doLast {
    //  ZipUtil.normaliseZipDates(archivePath.absolutePath)
    ZipUtil.normaliseZipDates(archiveFile.get().asFile.absolutePath)
  }
```

`normaliseZipDates` takes a String, I can't just pass it `archiveFile` and `archiveFile.absolutePath` gives "No such property: absolutePath".

At the moment, as shown above, I'm using `archiveFile.get().asFile.absolutePath` but that seems crazy verbose - what's the correct way to this?

Context: Using Gradle 6.9 at the moment, soon upgrading to to 7.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`println archiveFile.get().toString()` also seems to give full file path -

```
> Task :buildZip
/Users/xyz/Projects/gradle-scala/build/distributions/gradle-scala-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

but I would recommend to stick with `archiveFile.get().asFile.absolutePath`